# Initialising Colorbox on change event

Tags: jquery

I want to show a lightbox when the visitor click on the option that have the value 1001 :

```
$("#v65-cart-shipping-details select option[value='1001']").click(function() {
    $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
});
```

It doesn't work on Mac.

Comment: You're missing the outer most quotes ?

Comment: You're missing `()` around `colorbox`?

Comment: Please use a more meaningful Question title. What does "JQuery selector" have to do with this question.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$(function(){
    $("#v65-cart-shipping-details select").change(function() {
        if (this.value == '1001')
        $.colorbox({width:"580px", inline:true, href:"#subscribe_popup"});
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event on the `<select>` change, not on the `<option>` click.